# Why can a method marked that is hiding an implementation in the base class call the hidden method?

Tags: c#, .net, inheritance, method-hiding

I've been doing a little reading around the c# spec, and come across a scenario I didn't expect, and was hoping somebody could share some light.

I stumbled across the `new` keyword for hiding members of a base class within a derived class, and subsequently a few discussions over when to use `new` as opposed to an `override` on a `virtual` member.

I threw a little code sample in to my IDE, expecting to see a compilation error

```
public class BaseType
{
    public void method()
    {
        // do nothing
    }
}
public class DerivedType : BaseType
{
    public new void method()
    {
        base.method();
    }
}
```

but instead found this to be legal c#. Since the derived class has hidden the presence of `method()`, why am I still allowed to call it?

Cheers

Comment: Because you're hiding it from consumers of the `Derived` type.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to hide (remove) a base class's methods in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1125746/how-to-hide-remove-a-base-classs-methods-in-c)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `DerivedType` is hiding the method from the classes which will be inheriting `DerivedType`, and not from itself.
Note that, to hide the method, the class has to know there exists a method in it's parent class with the same name and same arguments. Hence a class hiding the method from it's own scope is logically incorrect.

Answer (score 3):

Do not mix method *hiding* with method *overriding*. They are two completely different beasts.

When hiding a method, you are only hiding it when accessing the method through the type that hides the method to begin with:

```
public class Foo
{
    public string Blah() { return "Hi from Foo!"; }
}

public class DerivedFoo: Foo
{
    public new string Blah() { return "Hi from DerivedFoo!"; }
}
```

Now we have the following behavior:

```
void TestFoos()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    DerivedFoo derivedFoo = new DerivedFoo();
    Foo derivedFooInDisguise = derivedFoo as Foo;

    Console.WriteLine(foo.Blah()); //Outputs "Hi from Foo!"
    Console.WriteLine(derivedFoo.Blah()); //Outputs "Hi from DerivedFoo!"
    Console.WriteLine(derivedFooInDisguise.Blah()); //Outputs "Hi from Foo!" 
}
```

Note, that this behavior is the same even if `Blah` is declared as `virtual`. The interesting part is the third call. The method is invoked through a `Foo` typed object. As its not a virtual call, `Foo.Blah()` is called, not `DerivedFoo.Blah()`.

Now this is completely different from *method overriding* where the virtual method call always resolves to the runtime type of the object, not the type through which you are calling it:

```
public class Foo
{
    public virtual string Blah() { return "Hi from Foo!"; }
}

public class DerivedFoo: Foo
{
    public override string Blah() { return "Hi from DerivedFoo!"; }
}
```

Now we have the following behavior:

```
void TestFoos()
{
    Foo foo = new Foo();
    DerivedFoo derivedFoo = new DerivedFoo();
    Foo derivedFooInDisguise = derivedFoo as Foo;

    Console.WriteLine(foo.Blah()); //Outputs "Hi from Foo!"
    Console.WriteLine(derivedFoo.Blah()); //Outputs "Hi from DerivedFoo!"
    Console.WriteLine(derivedFooInDisguise.Blah()); ////Outputs "Hi from DerivedFoo!"
}
```

Comment: While this is a good indication of the separation of one over the other, and it's appreciated, the question was more, why was the snipped posted legal c#, when my expectation was that this would be invalid.

Comment: @JamieR Sorry, I completely misunderstood your question. Out of curiosity, why do you find it surprising when hiding but not when overriding?

Comment: My mistake was assuming that the declaration of hiding the method of `BaseType` would make the method invisible immediately to `DerivedType`, whereas the method is in fact hidden for consumers and children of `DerivedType`.